# MAPI showing details of contacts

Tags: outlook, dialog, contacts, outlook-redemption

We are currently using MAPI to load contact information into a form.
Within a MapiSession we are creating a RDOAddressEntry "recepient" with this bit of code

```
using (MapiSession session = new MapiSession()) 
{
    //open outlook contact dialog
    RDOAddressEntry recipient = session.GetAddressEntryFromID(contact.EntryId);
    if (recipient.Type == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("type not defined");
    }

    recipient.Details(handle.ToInt32());
}
```

Our problem seems to be that the dialog that opens with the last line of code creates two different dialogs. One for exchange contacts and another one for SMTP contacts.

In the last version of our application it was always opening the same dialog for both RDOAddressEntry-types and we did NOT change anything in our code...

Can you help me fix this issue so that both SMTP and exchange will bring the same dialogs again?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you were getting the same dialog for both before - the dialog is actually provided by the particular address book provider, so it will be different for the entries from different providers.

Comment: It seems that the older version of the application loaded the dialog with a "Redemption.RDOAddressEntryClass"-Object, and now it is loaded with a "System._COMObject"-Object...

Comment: That wouldn't make any difference - that's just how the debugger represents that variable.

Comment: So what else could make the difference, that the same code now has different results?...

Comment: The only explanation is that even though you knew the address entry is from Exchange, it was treated as a one-off SMTP entry. Hard to be specific without having access to the environment where the code runs.

Comment: actually we did solve the problem!! We are now using the Microsoft.Office.Interop and it works as we want it to. So there seems to be a problem with Redemption...

Comment: Redemption uses the MAPI system, it does not deal with the address entry dialogs.- it calls IAddrBook::Details. It looks like OOM uses its own custom dialog.